# Django(Python) website Deploy page 500 error

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, cpanel, shared-hosting

I have deployed my Django website in Cpanel. The home page working fine but the other page not working. for example, when I visit the home page it opened but when I visit the about or contact us page it shows a 500 error. my website working perfectly in localhost but its problem with shared hosting(Cpanel)

Comment: You will have to check the error log for details about the error.

Comment: please tell me where is Django log file

Comment: You set it up. And please remember that Stack Overflow is about programming, not about server setup.